Tibble is not displaying fully in R Studio
I have no idea what happened but for some reason my tibbles randomly decided to not display fully, I've tried searching it up and implementing the 'fix" but the issue continues to persist
The file is a .qmd, Quarto
{r}
athletes %>% group_by(Sex) %>% summarize(n = n()) # Number of data points


This is a code, I can see the answers are right because when I press the pop-out options that displays the tibble in a brand new tab, female is 102 and male is 120 as it should be, but it doesn't display that correctly
I found some sources talking about going to Tools -> Global Options -> Console -> Display and changing the margin around, this did not change anything at all.
There were also some that suggested changing the "Limit output length" in the Tools -> Global Options -> Code -> Display, this did not work either.



@JonSpring Sorry I should have included that, this is a Quatro document (.qmd to be exact)

Do you have any special parameters in the YAML? Do you get the same problem if you restart R and run it again?

@JonSpring Nothing special in the YAML, haven't even touched it, I have closed it and opened it up multiple times and still the same problem

This looks like an options() setting affecting the tibble column width. Check here for how to check and/or adjust: link

What happens when you render your document to desired output format?

Could you please share some reproducible data?
